# Telerik Radtabstrip Auto Height

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How to set telerik radtabstrip Height as auto. .

I want to increase the height of tab as size of content increase.
i do not want scrollbar. I've searched but it will take fixed size only

Comment: You really could have used a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the PageView's Height:

ASPX:

```
<telerik:radtabstrip id="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" selectedindex="0" multipageid="RadMultipage1"> 
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab1" PageViewID=" RadMultipage1">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab2">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab3">
            </telerik:RadTab>
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:radtabstrip>
<telerik:radmultipage id="RadMultipage1" runat="server" selectedindex="0"> 
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView1" ContentUrl="Default2.aspx" /> 
    </telerik:radmultipage>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function resize() {
    var height = getDocHeight();
    var elements = window.top.document.getElementsByTagName("div");    

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var containerPageViewID = "RadPageView1";

        if (elements[i].id.indexOf(containerPageViewID) > -1) {
            elements[i].style.height = height + "px";
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", resize, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", resize);
else window.onload = resize;

function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return  Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

</script>
```

Source: [Telerik's documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-troubleshooting-set-height-to-pageview.html)

Comment: Are you talking about the RadTabStrip's Height or the RadMultiPage/Pageview's Height?